# NullpointerException on string-array android xml

Tags: android

Good day, Any idea why i could be getting a NullPointerException in the following code. I am trying to retrieve elements from a string-array in XML and test against a given value but i keep getting a NullpointerException on the first line of the code below.

```
 String [] position = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.google_weather_conditions); // NullpointerException here        
            for(String check: position){
               String test_condition = check;
               if(this.condition.equals(test_condition)){
                  weather_conditions = test_condition;
               }
                    }
```

here is the strings.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
     <string name="Clear">Clear</string>
     <string name="Sunny">Sunny</string>
     <string name="Mostly_Sunny">Mostly Sunny</string>
     <string name="Partly_Sunny">Partly Sunny</string>
     <string name="Cloudy">Cloudy</string>
    <string name="Mostly_Cloudy">Mostly Cloudy</string>
    <string name="Partly_Cloudy">Partly Cloudy</string>
    <string name="Rain">Rain</string>

     <string-array name="google_weather_conditions">
            <item>@string/Clear</item>
            <item>@string/Sunny</item>
            <item>@string/Mostly_Sunny</item>
            <item>@string/Partly_Sunny</item>
            <item>@string/Cloudy</item>
            <item>@string/Mostly_Cloudy</item>
            <item>@string/Partly_Cloudy</item>
            <item>@string/Rain</item>
        </string-array>


    </resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely `context` is null at the point of the NPE.

Comment: Thanks! that was it. i was doing it in a class that extends nothing, so i had to pass in the context of my Service.

Answer (score 0):

```
context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.google_weather_conditions); // NullpointerException here
```

The following could be null:

- `context`
- return value of `context.getResources()`
- `R`
- `R.array`
- `R.array.google_weather_conditons`

Time to either step through with a debugger, or break it down, line by line and see where it occurs.

What is `R`?

Comment: `R` is a class name; `R.array` is a nested class; `google_weather_conditions` is an int value. These are all generated by the build process from XML. Considering that this is Android code, the only realistic problem here is `context`.